# Redshift unnest alternative

Tags: postgresql, amazon-redshift

I have a field that I'm trying to unnest essentially. Since Redshift is still on Postgres 8.0, I've been trying to find a way to create a function to do this, but am a bit stuck. The only thing that's difficult is that this field can have multiple entries.

So the field looks like: `Aleppo-09-SY ; Chicago-IL-US`. Sometimes, it'll be blank or have 1 entry like `Chicago-IL-US`.

Is it possible to create a UDF to do this splitting?

Comment: What's the maximum of individual values stuffed into one column?

Comment: I ended up doing the work before loading into Redshift using Python since this didn't seem possible. I still don't think it's possible within Redshift